# Map Super+[Left|Right] to Home/End

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

How do I map key "Super" so, when combined with Left/Right, it produces keycode Home/End?

My current setxkbmap:

```
setxkbmap \
  -model pc105 \
  -layout 'us(dvorak-intl),us(alt-intl)' \
  -option \
  -option grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle \
  -option compose:rwin
```

Comment: Just FYI, Gedit honors the `gtktextview` shortcuts: **Ctrl+Shift+PageUp** and **Ctrl+Shift+PageDown** to select (or continue to select) all the way to the beginning and respectively the end of the line. I don't think that's what you're after, though... :)

Comment: I have updated this question so more specific to root of what I want...not just for gedit but as broadly as possible within X.

Comment: Possible other answer: http://superuser.com/questions/469004/remap-superarrow-key-to-home-end

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do it with just a setkxbmap option, as no default option does what you want.

But you can do it by defining key behaviour at a lower level.

The page http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/ helped me to understand and find a way to do it.

Create a file ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd where you put the output of setxkbmap, it will be your base keyboard definition; eg:

```
setxkbmap -print > ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd
```

then we will create a `~/.xkb/types/mytypes` file and put the following in:

```
partial
xkb_types "super_level2" {
    Virtual_modifiers Super;
    type "SUPER_LEVEL2" {
        modifiers= Super;
        map[Super]= Level2;
        level_name[Level1]= "Base";
        level_name[Level2]= "Super";
    };
};
```

it defines a type SUPER_LEVEL2 that will allow to easily define symbols sent when a key is pressed with <kbd>Super</kbd>.

then, in the `~/.xkb/symbols/mysymbols` put the following lines:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "super_arrows_home_end" {
    key <LEFT>  {
        type[Group1] = "SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Left,   Home      ]
    };
    key <RGHT>  {
        type[Group1] = "SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Right,  End       ]
    };
};
```

(note the use of the "SUPER_LEVEL2 type we defined, it means that the second (level 2) symbol on the symbols line is triggered when pressing Super key (instead of Shift key).

Finally, edit the `~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd` file to load the snippets we wrote:

- in the `xkb_types` line add `+mytypes(super_level2)` inside the quotes
- in the `xkb_symbols` line add `+mysymbols(super_arrows_home_end)` in the quotes.

Now you can load it with

```bsh
xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY
```

Test your left/right keys, they should work as you wanted.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 16.04. Super key still opens the Dash Home.

Comment: @PeterDotchev Your DE will always come first, so you have to disable or remap the keyboard shortcuts first.

Comment: That works well. How would you go about and map `super`+`shift`+`left` to `shift`+`home` and `super`+`shift`+`right` to `shift`+`end` for selection?

Comment: You cannot map a key or combination of keys to a *combination* of keys. You can only map to another key (symbol of key); or to a string. If you happen to know a string (with escape codes and such) that is what you actually want to produce, then you can map to it. So, you should look at what is *produced* by shift+home on your current keyboard and map to that. Note however that modern programs that allow defining key shortcuts are likely to bypass that; on the other hand they usually let you redefine shortcuts by just typing whatever combination you like.

Comment: I am getting the an error when following those instructions: 
```syntax error: line 12 of mysymbols
last scanned symbol is: End
Error:            Error interpreting include file "mysymbols"
                  Exiting
                  Abandoning symbols file "(null)"
Error:            success in unknown
                  Couldn't write keyboard description to :0
```
I am running Linux Mint 19 (based of Ubuntu 18). I understand that the original answer is quite old, so probably something has changed in the format. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: It seems there is a trailing thing at the end of your file that causes a parsing error; how do you create the file ? you typed it yourself or did a cut and paste ? what if you try with an empty mysymbols file ?

Comment: Worked in 20.04, sort of. I also added `<UP>` with `Up, Prior` and `DOWN` with `Down, Next` in mysymbols for PgUp and PgDn. Keys work in terminal, browser address bar and gedit, but not browser pages or some other programs like VSCode. For startup I tried .xinitrc, which doesn't fire, and .xsessionrc, which does but the keys seem to be overridden later, so I set up a Startup Application with a command that doesn't use any $ vars or tilde for the home folder, i.e. `xkbcomp -I/home/d/.xkb /home/d/.xkb/keymap/mykbd :0`. I also had to disable/change the Settings > KB Shortcuts for Super + Arrows.