# How to remap a key combination to a key?

Tags: linux, key-mapping, xmodmap, x-server

Is it possible to remap a key combination to a key in X server based system, so that for example if I press <kbd>End</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow_up</kbd>, keycode for <kbd>Home</kbd> is generated? Google seems to be silent on this issue. It would be great if there was a solution, since it would open up many possibilities for more convenient keyboard mapping.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/469004/remap-superarrow-key-to-home-end) similar question over at superuser.
Something like

```
"xdotool key Home"
  End + Up
```

in the `.xbindkeysrc` file should suffice.

If you really want to try to use xmodmap, a start would be to map either the `End` key or the `Up` key to a modifier key in .`Xmodmap`. For example, you could grab your two keys with `xev` and map the `End` key to `mode_switch` with

```
keycode NN("End" keycode) = mode_switch
```

and then map the mode_switch part of `Up` to `Home`

```
keycode NN("Up" keycode) = Up NoSymbol Home
```

But I am not sure about that part, you will have to experiment.
What will definitely work is to let your desktop environmnet do the work(dconf etc.).

Another clue might be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65434/map-superleftright-to-home-end).