# Map Insert key to End/Home

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm trying to remap my Insert key to End and shift+Insert to Home on Ubuntu 16.10. Inspired by [Map Super+[Left|Right] to Home/End](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65434/map-superleftright-to-home-end) and some other resources I made the following mysymbols file:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "insert_end_home" {
   key <INS>  {[    End, Home     ]};
};
```

It works for the `End`, but shift+Insert does not produce the `Home` function. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

After modifying with `xmodmap` as suggested by @dirkt I still get only Home or only End.  Here is the output of `xev` when I press `Insert` and then when I press `shift+Insert`. There is indeed a `FocusOut` event, but what does it mean?

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xed, subw 0x0, time 56790713, (-342,308), root:(439,360),
    state 0x0, keycode 118 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 110
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xed, subw 0x0, time 56790753, (-342,308), root:(439,360),
    state 0x0, keycode 118 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 110
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xed, subw 0x0, time 56796591, (-342,308), root:(439,360),
    state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xed, subw 0x0, time 56796755, (-342,308), root:(439,360),
    state 0x1, keycode 118 (keysym 0xff57, End), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 115
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xed, subw 0x0, time 56796811, (-342,308), root:(439,360),
    state 0x1, keycode 118 (keysym 0xff57, End), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 115
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xed, subw 0x0, time 56797003, (-342,308), root:(439,360),
    state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    atom 0x168 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 56802723, state PropertyNewValue
```

Also, here's the output of `xmodmap -pm`:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to make your own xkb files, why don't you just use `xmodmap` and `~/.Xmodmap`?

Comment: Because I searched for solutions before asking questions and that seemed to be the suggested way.  Now I have explicitly looked ad xmodmap and it seems sufficient indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write `xkb` files is difficult, use `xmodmap` instead.

The standard name from where to automatically load a mapping on login is `~/.Xmodmap`, some display managers do this out of the box, for some display managers you have to modify the login scripts.

Don't try to use `xmodmap` explictily in `.profile` or similar, this will give you trouble if you log in via `ssh` etc.

**Edit**: As explained in `man xmodmap`, you can't describe `keycode` combinations with <kbd>Alt</kbd> this way, only with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and with the <kbd>Mode_Switch</kbd> key:

> Up  to  eight  keysyms  may  be
>   attached  to  a  key, however the last four are not used in any
>   major X server implementation.  The first keysym is  used  when
>   no  modifier  key  is pressed in conjunction with this key, the
>   second with Shift, the third when the Mode_switch key  is  used
>   with  this  key  and  the  fourth when both the Mode_switch and
>   Shift keys are used.

For my keyboard, I've assigned <kbd>Mode_Switch</kbd> to the left Windows-Key (which happens to be `Super_L` on my keyboard);

```
keysym Super_L = Mode_switch
```

So either designate some key you don't use otherwise as <kbd>Mode_Switch</kbd>, or read up on how `xkbd` words. The [Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058) may help.

Comment: With xmodmap I can easily map the Insert key to either Home or End but not both. Even by putting `keycode 118 = Home End End End End End` all combinations with the Insert key will only do Home.

Comment: I just did `xmodmap -e 'keycode 118 = Home End'` on my machine, tested with `xev`, and it works fine. How did you exactly try to load your modification?

Comment: When I run your command, Home works, but not End. I tried with all possible modifiers (shift, ctrl, alt, + combinations of those).  It will always act as Home.

Comment: For me, it works with `Shift` as modifier. What is your modifier assignment? (Update question with output of `xmodmap -pm`). Also do `modmap -pke | grep 118` to verify that you set the keysyms correctly.

Comment: Also, look closely at the output of `xev` when you press the newly configured `Shift-Insert`. If you get any FocusOut events, or some other events that look fishy, some application or the window manager is stealing this key event.

Comment: I edited my question as you suggested.  Thanks

Comment: There's very clearly an `End` keypress event (`keysym 0xff57, End`) when used together with `Shift`. What makes you think `End` doesn't work? Maybe some application isn't interpreting it correctly? Possibly the application interprets it as `Shift-End`, because `Shift` is pressed? If yes, you need to use another modifier key instead of `Shift`.

Comment: You are correct: in a text editor , Shift-Insert is interpreted as Shift-End (selecting everything until end of line).  I can't obtain a pure End.  I tried to modify the command to `xmodmap -e 'keycode 118 = Home NoSymbol NoSymbol End`  in order to use the `Alt-Insert` combination as `End`, but to no avail :-(