# Setting ALT + ARROWS LEFT,RIGHT to HOME,END in xkb

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

I'm trying for days to set the (left) <kbd>ALT</kbd> + arrows keys (left/right) keybindings in `xkb`.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> to <kbd>HOME</kbd>

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> to <kbd>END</kbd>

These keybindings should work together with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> as well.

I just switched to GNOME 40 + Wayland and my previous solution (`xbindkeys`, `xvkbd`) doesn't work and more. Now I'm struggly to get my keybinds back.

I followed this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65923) but I wasn't able to successful map the keys. I also wonder how to make the mapping permanent.

Here is what I have so far:

`setxkbmap -print`

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

`~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd`:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)+mysymbols(alt_arrows_home_end)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

`~/.xkb/symbols/mysymbols`:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "alt_arrows_home_end" {
key <LEFT> {  
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]=  [ Left, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<HOME>)] };  
key <RGHT> {   
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Right, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<END>)] };
};
```

When I try to load it `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY` I'm getting bunch of warnings + the keybinds doesn't work.

```
Keycodes above 256 (e.g. <I256>) are not supported by X and are ignored
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86BrightnessAuto
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86DisplayOff
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Info
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AspectRatio
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86DVD
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Audio
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ChannelUp
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ChannelDown
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Break
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86VideoPhone
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ZoomReset
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Editor
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86GraphicsEditor
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Presentation
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Database
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Voicemail
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Addressbook
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86DisplayToggle
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SpellCheck
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ContextMenu
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MediaRepeat
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF8610ChannelsUp
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF8610ChannelsDown
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Images
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NotificationCenter
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86PickupPhone
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86HangupPhone
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Fn
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Fn_Esc
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86FnRightShift
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric0
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric1
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric2
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric3
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric4
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric5
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric6
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric7
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric8
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric9
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NumericStar
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NumericPound
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NumericA
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NumericB
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NumericC
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NumericD
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraFocus
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86WPSButton
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraZoomIn
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraZoomOut
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraUp
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraDown
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraLeft
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraRight
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AttendantOn
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AttendantOff
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AttendantToggle
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86LightsToggle
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ALSToggle
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Buttonconfig
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Taskmanager
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Journal
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ControlPanel
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AppSelect
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Screensaver
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86VoiceCommand
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Assistant
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86BrightnessMin
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86BrightnessMax
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdInputAssistPrev
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdInputAssistNext
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdInputAssistPrevgroup
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdInputAssistNextgroup
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdInputAssistAccept
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdInputAssistCancel
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86RightUp
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86RightDown
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86LeftUp
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86LeftDown
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86RootMenu
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MediaTopMenu
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric11
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Numeric12
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AudioDesc
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF863DMode
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NextFavorite
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86StopRecord
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86PauseRecord
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86VOD
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Unmute
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86FastReverse
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SlowReverse
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Data
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86OnScreenKeyboard
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86PrivacyScreenToggle
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SelectiveScreenshot
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro1
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro2
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro3
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro4
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro5
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro6
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro7
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro8
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro9
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro10
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro11
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro12
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro13
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro14
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro15
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro16
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro17
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro18
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro19
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro20
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro21
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro22
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro23
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro24
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro25
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro26
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro27
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro28
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro29
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Macro30
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MacroRecordStart
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MacroRecordStop
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MacroPresetCycle
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MacroPreset1
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MacroPreset2
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MacroPreset3
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdLcdMenu1
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdLcdMenu2
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdLcdMenu3
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdLcdMenu4
Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86KbdLcdMenu5
Warning:          Key <I372> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I382> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I256> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I366> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I379> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I380> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I383> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I397> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I400> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I401> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I405> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I410> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I411> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I418> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I419> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I424> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I425> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I426> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I427> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I428> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I429> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I430> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I431> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I432> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I433> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I434> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I435> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I436> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I437> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I438> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I439> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I440> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I441> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I442> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I443> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I444> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I445> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I446> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I447> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I448> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I449> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I450> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I452> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I453> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I454> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I472> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I473> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I493> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I505> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I506> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I507> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I508> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I509> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I510> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I511> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I512> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I513> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I514> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I520> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I521> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I522> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I523> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I524> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I525> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I526> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I527> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I528> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I529> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I530> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I531> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I532> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I533> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I534> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I535> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I536> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I537> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I538> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I539> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I540> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I541> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I542> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I543> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I544> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I545> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I546> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I547> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I548> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I549> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I550> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I568> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I569> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I584> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I585> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I586> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I587> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I588> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I589> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I590> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I591> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I592> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I600> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I601> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I616> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I617> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I618> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I619> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I620> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I621> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I622> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I623> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I624> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I625> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I626> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I627> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I628> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I629> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I630> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I631> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I632> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I633> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I634> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I635> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I636> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I637> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I638> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I639> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I640> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I641> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I642> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I664> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I665> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I666> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I667> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I668> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I669> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I670> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I671> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I672> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I673> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I674> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I675> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I676> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I677> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I678> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I679> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I680> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I681> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I682> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I683> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I684> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I685> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I686> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I687> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I688> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I689> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I690> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I691> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I692> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I693> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I696> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I697> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I698> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I699> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I700> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I701> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I704> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I705> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I706> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I707> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
Warning:          Key <I708> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
No symbols defined for <AB11> (keycode 97)
No symbols defined for <JPCM> (keycode 103)
No symbols defined for <I120> (keycode 120)
No symbols defined for <AE13> (keycode 132)
No symbols defined for <I149> (keycode 149)
No symbols defined for <I154> (keycode 154)
No symbols defined for <I168> (keycode 168)
No symbols defined for <I178> (keycode 178)
No symbols defined for <I183> (keycode 183)
No symbols defined for <I184> (keycode 184)
No symbols defined for <FK19> (keycode 197)
No symbols defined for <FK24> (keycode 202)
No symbols defined for <I217> (keycode 217)
No symbols defined for <I219> (keycode 219)
No symbols defined for <I222> (keycode 222)
No symbols defined for <I230> (keycode 230)
No symbols defined for <I248> (keycode 248)
```

Comment: I am also on Wayland and getting the very same warnings. I am using sway and I think I have to do it this way, since I'm trying to change some keycodes and sway-input doesn't provide a simpler way to do that. In your case, if you're also using sway, since you just want to change symbols, I think something like `swaymsg input type:keyboard xkb_layout mysymbols(alt_arrows_home_end)` would work. Please let me know if that helps and in case you have figured out anything about this problem and the warnings since posting your question. BTW, it may be good to put 'wayland' in the question & tags.

Comment: My hypothesis is that these problems might be due to `xkbcomp` interacting with `xwayland` rather than our respective compositors or `wl-roots` directly. See here: https://blog.debiania.in.ua/posts/2021-06-10-remapping-keys-under-wayland.html Personally I am going to try passing my .xkb file to `sway-input`'s `xkb_file` argument. If you use sway too, you could try the same. I'll try to remember to report back. In case I forget, feel free to tag me.

Comment: Yep, `swaymsg input type:keyboard xkb_file {path_to_my_xkb_file}` worked for me on sway, rather than trying to apply the .xkb file with `xkbcomp`,. Hopefully this at least helps point you in the right direction if you use a different compositor. You should consider adding that detail to the question.